# Put images in container divs in random groups of 1, 2 or 3 elements each

Tags: jquery

i have a series of images
let's say

```
<img src="1.jpg" />
<img src="2.jpg" />
<img src="3.jpg" />
<img src="4.jpg" />
<img src="5.jpg" />
<img src="6.jpg" />
```

so on and so forth.

and what i need to happen is to wrap in random 1,2 or 3 elements inside a div.
so result would be

```
<div>
 <img src="1.jpg" >
</div>
<div>
 <img src="2.jpg" ><img src="3.jpg"><img src="4.jpg">
</div>
<div>
 <img src="5.jpg" ><img src="6.jpg" >
</div>
```

any ideas how to do this?

Thank you!

------ EDIT -------
How to do the same thing but this time the images are wrapped within an ? simply replacing img in Bojan's doesn't seem to do the trick..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of that

Here is html

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
</div>
```

And here is javascript

```
function wrapInsideDiv(){
    while($("#container>img").length > 0){
        var images = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
        var div = $("<div/>");
        $("#container").append(div);
        $("#container>img").each(function(index, elem){
            if(index + 1 < images){
             $(elem).appendTo(div);
            }
        });
    }
}
wrapInsideDiv();​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZD8JY/)

Comment: That doesn't work. Check the page source and you'll see it only wraps one image at a time, while skipping some.

Comment: I've been trying to use this. however, this time the images are wrapped with <a href...> and this breaks. I would essentially like the same to happen just images wrapped in a link.

Comment: You need to add display:block to <a>. When you add this css link will behave like div with default values, because div is display:block by default and is display:inline. Try [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZD8JY/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this ([HERE'S A DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VKHTV/2/), you'll possibly need to check the page source to see the results):

HTML

```
<img src="img.png" />
<img src="img.png" />
<img src="img.png" />
<img src="img.png" />
<!-- etc. ->

<div id="container"></div>
```

JS

```
var randomNr, currentDiv;

$("img").each(function(){
    // if this is the first iteration, or if randomNr is larger than 3
    if(randomNr == undefined || randomNr > 3){
        // get a new random nr between 1 and 3
        randomNr = randomXToY(1, 3);
        // create a new div to put the images in
        currentDiv = $("<div></div>");
        $("#container").append(currentDiv);
    }

    // move image to currentDiv
    $(this).appendTo(currentDiv);
    randomNr++;   
});


// function to get random number
function randomXToY(minVal,maxVal){
    var randVal = minVal+(Math.random()*(maxVal-minVal));
    return Math.round(randVal);
}
```

This generates a random nr between 1 and 3, loops over all images and counts up to 3 from that number. Every time the random number gets larger than 3, a new div is created to put the images in.

Comment: Wow that works amazing! thank you! this was my first question on stackoverflow (BEST TEACHER ever) and i must say, what an amazing community. Thank you! +karma

Comment: You're welcome, please accept this answer by clicking the 'V' on the left if this answered your question. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to each of the images and with javascript or jquery, generate a random number or a serie of random numbers and grab them using this variable and push them into certain divs you may want.